# What is wrong with my parsec parser?

Tags: haskell

I would like to get this parser to work. I am currently not quite sure where the error is. It is largely taken from the Parsec section of "Write you a scheme"

One more question: if it eventually works, are there any means to ensure that the string that starts with a question mark is always the last in the list?

```
input_text :: String
input_text = "Eval (isFib::, 1000, ?BOOL)"

data LTuple
   = Command [LTuple]
   | Number Integer
   | String String
   | Query Bool
   deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

data Command = Rd | Read | In | Take | Wr | Out | Eval
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  case parse lindaCmd "example" input_text of
    Left err -> print err
    Right res -> putStrLn $ "I parsed: '" ++ res ++ "'"

parseList :: Parser lindaTpl
parseList = liftM Command $ sepBy1 lindaCmd  ( symbol "," )

lindaCmd =   string "rd"
         <|> string "take"
         <|> string "out"
         <|> string "eval"
         <|> do char '('
                x <- try parseList
                char ')'return x
```

The current error message is:

```
test.hs:30:48:
    Couldn't match expected type `ParsecT s0 u0 m0 sep0'
                with actual type `String -> ParsecT s1 u1 m1 String'
    In the return type of a call of `symbol'
    Probable cause: `symbol' is applied to too few arguments
    In the second argument of `sepBy1', namely `(symbol ",")'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `sepBy1 lindaCmd (symbol ",")'

test.hs:38:17:
    The function `char' is applied to three arguments,
    but its type `Char -> ParsecT s0 u0 m0 Char' has only one
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: char ')' return x
    In the second argument of `(<|>)', namely
      `do { char '(';
            x <- try parseList;
            char ')' return x }'
    In the second argument of `(<|>)', namely
      `string "eval"
       <|>
         do { char '(';
              x <- try parseList;
              char ')' return x }'
```

Comment: You have `char ')'return x` all on one line at the end of `lindaCmd`.

Answer (score 3):

First error:

```
parseList = liftM Command $ sepBy1 lindaCmd  ( symbol "," )
```

should probably be

```
parseList = liftM Command $ sepBy1 lindaCmd  ( string "," )
```

Second error, as dbaupp points out,

```
     <|> do char '('
            x <- try parseList
            char ')'return x
```

should be

```
     <|> do char '('
            x <- try parseList
            char ')'
            return x
```

That should fix the two errors you have for now, but I haven't checked to see whether there are any more.

---

Edit:

You have

```
parseList :: Parser lindaTpl
```

but I expect you want

```
parseList :: Parser LTuple
```

I expect you also want

```
lindaCmd :: Parser LTuple
```

and will have to modify the body of `lindaCmd` also --- all except the final branch seem to want to have the type `Parser String`...

Comment: Concerning the symbol I was actually following the example from here: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/latest/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Combinator.html#v:sepBy

Comment: `symbol` appears to be a field of the [`GenTokenParser`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/latest/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Token.html#t:GenTokenParser) datatype. The example you followed is either outdated or was always in error.

Comment: Gives still a problem in the lindaCmd, either the String because LindaTpl was expected or the the other way around in the last line.